# Docker, монтирование файла из контейнера на хост

Tags: docker, mount

Требуется смонтировать файл из контейнера на хост таким образом, чтобы при изменении на хосте файл не менялся внутри контейнера.

Суть проблемы в том, что на хосте есть файл package.json, этот же файл с изменениями приходит в образе из которого создаётся новый контейнер.
Так вот, файл с хоста перетирает файл контейнера, а требуется ровно противоположное (после выполнения команды `docker pull` и создании контейнера файл package.json должен перезаписывать файл хоста)

Пример из docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  some:
    container_name: some_container
    image: ${TARGET_IMAGE}
    volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: var_www
          target: /var/www
          read_only: false
        - ${PWD}/package.json:/var/www/package.json
     networks:
        - internal
networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge  
volumes:
  var_www:
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сам смысл контейнеризации в том чтобы изолировать содержимое и процессы контейнера внутри него.

Поэтому то, что вы хотите не реализуемо. Если вам НЕ нужен package.json с хоста в контейнере не монтируйте его.

Если вы хотите иметь внутри контейнера какой-то иной package.json создавайте его через директивы в Dockerfile.